# Must all the server addresses be known and well-defined before starting the ensemble?

Tags: configuration, apache-zookeeper

Must all the server addresses be known and well-defined before starting the ensemble? It looks like the config file always has a list of servers,

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

But I want the servers to join (by using something like a common token or one known peer)

Comment: You should probably specify (not just in the tags) what software you're using, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic configuration is only supported starting from `3.5.0`
The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AF8pIfQbN5cKxe0c4cQ4_DW6ZjBJqSkyANcTGUwkzjc/edit)
Also worth reading [this](http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/dynamic-reconfiguration-of-zookeeper) page for similar discussion